# Making your python code execute on all computers

Tags: python, python-2.7, exe

I have written a python GUI application.I want to run the code on my friend's computer who doesn't have python interpreter in his computer and that he can't download since he can't connect to the internet.How do I make that happen?

Comment: If you can copy your program to your friend's computer, why can't you also install Python (via USB drive, etc.)?

Comment: The friend I am talking works in a company which doesn't allow any kind of external devices to be connected onto his computer.Hence I wanted to email him the executable

Comment: Please accept an answer if your problem was resolved, which it appears to have been. To do this, click the green check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use py2exe (for Windows), py2app (for Mac), or cx_freeze (for Linux) to bundle the Python interpreter, your program, and the standard library into an executable you can use on a machine with no Python at all.

PS: If your friend's computer isn't on the Internet, however you'd get him your program, you can also get him the kits for Python, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) is a library that allows you to compile Python executables for Windows.  There's also [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/), which is cross-platform.